# Make bootstrap carousel background transparent

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am a newbie in CSS , and I wanted to make a carousel transparent on top of the colored div, how can I achieve this ?

Below is my current results :
[image]

Then this is my `html` code :

```
<div class="second-phase">
        <!-- Tab for Carousel-->
        <div id="products-page-carousel"></div>

        <!--Carousel View-->
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide"  data-ride="carousel">

            <!-- The slideshow -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" >
                <div class="carousel-item active" id="my-carousel-bg" >
                    <center>
                        <img src="/media/g01hgi0m/branded-basin.png" alt="Los Angeles" width="30%" height="30%">
                    </center>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" id="my-carousel-bg">
                    <center>
                        <img src="/media/waqd3xdw/branded-milk-crate.png" alt="Chicago" width="10%" height="10%">
                    </center>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" id="my-carousel-bg">
                    <center>
                        <img src="/media/g01hgi0m/branded-basin.png" alt="New York" width="30%" height="30%">
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
                <img src="/media/aqrnoaxe/asset-1.png" width="17%"/>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
                <img src="/media/xqwj1jpx/asset-3.png" width="17%"/>
            </a>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

Then, also my `CSS` is here :

```
.second-phase{
    margin-top: -170px;
    height: 700px;
}
#my-carousel-bg{
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity: 2;
}
```

This is how my output is supposed to be :

[image]

Comment: you are using the same `id=""` on multiple `div's`, for multiple `div's` use `class` instead also, is the  `<div class="carousel-item" id="my-carousel-bg">` the div with the white background?

Comment: @RamondeVries, only `id="my-carousel-bg"` is the one with the transparent background, am wondering where the white background comes from

Comment: I understand you applied `background-color: transparent` to that `div`, but is it really transparent or is that pierce of css not working? try looking into the inspect element of your browser, turning some div's on and off and see when the white background goes away

Comment: When I inspect in the browser, and I change to this div `<div class="carousel-item active" id="my-carousel-bg" >` to different colors it changes the background , but when I use the color code for transparent it doesn't work

Comment: When i try to replicate the problem, there is no white background, `background transparent` works for me, are you sure there is no other css still overruling, or other div's causing the white background, so the `background:transparent` works but another white div is hiding behind it

Answer (score 0):

You can not have multiple id tags on a single page. They should be unique within the entire document. Try changing from an id to a class and see if that fixes the problem.